# Have there been more distinctive names suggested for neutrino mass states $\nu_1, \nu_2, \nu_3$?

Tags: soft-question, standard-model, terminology, neutrinos

The different mass states of [neutrinos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino) are [generally](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2012/reviews/rpp2012-rev-neutrino-mixing.pdf) named $\nu_1, \nu_2, \nu_3$.

By comparison, the names of quark mass states (`up`, `down`, `strange`, and so on) or the names of mass states of charged leptons (`electron`, `muon`, `tau(on)`) appear more distinctive, or whimsical.

Have there been perhaps any suggestions of correspondingly less generic "proper names" for each of the (three distinct) neutrino mass states?

Comment: Arent neutrinos referred to as flavours now ?

Comment: @rijul gupta: "_Aren't neutrinos referred to as flavours now ?_" -- As far as quarks and charged leptons are concerned, "flavor" is apparently synonymous to "mass state"; and they are denoted by the familiar names mentioned in the question. On the other hand, the widely used neutrino names $\nu_e, \nu_{\mu}, \nu_{\tau}$ are referring to [mixing states](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/81570/12262), not to mass states.

Comment: My point, [exactly](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/253751/66086).  I  suspect they are waiting till they resolve the hierarchy. The present placeholder names, 1,2,3 are a perpetual source of confusion, as evinced in the comment question!

Comment: Do you have your own suitable names?

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos: "_Do you have your own suitable names?_" – Well: being put on the spot (and just back from vacation) I'd like to call those three: `vanilla`, `strawberry`, and `chocolate`.

Comment: I recall there was a competition for such in the [Long-Baseline Neutrino Oscillation Newsletter]( http://www.hep.anl.gov/ndk/longbnews/), but I forget when. Your names evoke flavors, though...

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos: "_[...] Your names evoke flavors, though..._" -- Bingo!.

Answer (score 1):

No. The data is analyzed with $\nu_1, \nu_2,\nu_3 $, well defined by their mixing matrices in the PDG, but, before the resolution of the hierarchy, they cannot be identified firmly with the [classroom poster placeholder names](http://www.cpepphysics.org/images/2014-fund-chart.jpg) $\nu_L, \nu_M,\nu_H $, Lightest, Middle, Heaviest.

In the normal hierarchy, the two sets identify ordinally; ultimately, after the resolution of the hierarchy,  somebody will think of good names--but not as good as my linked answer's: Huey, Dewey, and Ratatouille, needless to say...

The PDG poster above is a vast advance w.r.t. the older version of that poster featuring the oxymoronic weak-charged-current "eigen"states $\nu_e,\nu_\mu,\nu_\tau$, regrettably still featured in dark corners of [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_particles#Leptons), and often referred to as "lepton flavor eigenstates", an absurd and confusing name indicating lepton flavor is thereby ipso facto violated!!